# Split an html row into multiple (sub) rows

Tags: html, html-table, row

How can I split a row in a html table into multiple (sub) rows? (I don't mean to use `rowspan` to span multiple rows because I am using a rails gem called `sync` that is constrained to updating a single table row at a time).

For example, how can I create a single row in a table, that:

- in column one, has a single row
- in column two, is split into 2 sub rows
- in column three, is split into 4 sub rows (row one from the previous column is split into 2 sub rows, and row 2 from the previous column is split into 2 sub rows).

This is just an example. I need to be able to dynamically decide the way the rows will be split at run time.

Edit: see below for structure as described in bullet points above (although note i'm trying to achieve this structure within a single table row, i.e. without using `rowspan`)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>1</td>
        <td rowspan=2>2</td>
        <td >3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td >4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>2</td>
        <td >5</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td >6</td>    
     </tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/40ukzvz1/

Comment: Provide us your HTML code that we can work with and describe what's not working there for you.

Comment: I don't have sample html code as I don't know how to make the 'sub' row structure described in the question. I'm looking for guidance or example code on how I could do this.

Comment: So show us your structure without 'subs`, and how you thing it should look with 'subs' on http://jsfiddle.net/ Basicly we wont do your job, we will answer your questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try nesting tables so that each table structure is not affected by the cell it sits in.

See code example:

```html
<table width="100%" border bgcolor="red">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border bgcolor="green">
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border bgcolor="blue">
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border bgcolor="yellow">
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```